# How to use Elasticsearch to "randomize" search results in PHP?

Tags: php, search, random, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use Elasticsearch's function score but other ways are invited as well.

My existing search looks like this:

```
$searchParams['body']['query']['filtered']['query']["match_all"] = array("boost" => 1);
```

How do I add function_score to this search? Here's what I have right now

```
$randomScore = new \stdClass();
// will be date or userid in the future
$randomScore->seed = 5; 
$functionScore = array(
            array("random_score" => $randomScore)
        );
$searchParams['body']['query']['function_score']['functions'] = $functionScore;
$queryResponse = $client->search($searchParams);
```

This seems really close to being correct. I just need some more brain power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Nest your query inside the 'functions_score' array
2. The functions need to be nested within an extra array []

The following worked for me, change it to your needs accordingly:

```
    $params = array();

    $params['body']['size'] = 10;
    $params['body']['from'] = 0;

    $random = new \stdClass();
    $random->seed = time(); //change this to make randomization consistent, e.g. user id
    $params['body']['query']['function_score']['functions'][]['random_score'] = $random;
    $params['body']['query']['function_score']['query']['bool']['must_not'] = array(
        'term' => array(
            '_id' => $this->get('currentPageId'),
         )
    );
    $params['body']['query']['function_score']['query']['bool']['must'] = array(
        'term' => array(
            'isAlias' => false
         )
    );
```